# Wrong browser User Agent

Tags: 11.04, firefox

I just finished installed Ubuntu 11.04. When I point my web browser to http://whatsmyuseragent.com/ , then it reports my User Agent as :

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows 98)

I get the same results with Firefox 4.0/7.0/8.0 & Chromium 14 & Konqueror which leads me to believe that it is an OS issue, rather than a browser specific issue

I have tried Firefox User Agent Switcher, didn't work

I have tried specifying the User Agent setting when launching Chrome, that didn't work either

I suspect it is because those extensions / options alters the browsers User Agent settings in Javascript and not the underlying header that the browser sends. See http://browserspy.dk/useragent.php for the 2 different user agents.

### Anybody have idea any ideas how I can update it?

Firebug says:

```
Host: whatsmyuseragent.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,/;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Proxy-Authorization: Basic Hello Bob
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that you're going through a proxy which alters the user agent header.

Check with Wireshark (or Firebug + its network tab) if the correct agent header is being sent.

Comment: I ran Firebug + its network tab as you suggested 

Got the following results

Host: whatsmyuseragent.com
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: en-us
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
    Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
    Proxy-Authorization: Basic Hello Bob

Comment: then you've probably got a proxy in your network that modifies the user-agent header.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.

i will ask the other ubuntu users in our company if they are experiencing the same issue and then take it from there

Comment: It's been solved.

The problem wasn't with the corporate proxy, but the fact that I was using a third party proxy on my localbox (ntlmaps).